# Dropdown menu and nav issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've just tried to design a dropdown menu for my navigation. Unfortunately they whole nav and the dropdown is flickering now, when I hover the dropdown button in my nav. The dropdown menu also disappears, when I try to click it.

I can't give you pieces of my code, because Stackoverflow transforms it directly into HTML (don't know why), so I just can give you a link to my test page: http://keinkopf.de/designs/1/

EDIT:

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="block1">Start</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="block2">Themen</a>
<ul>
<br />
<li><a href="#">1</a></li><br />
<li><a href="#">2</a></li><br />
<li><a href="#">3</a></li><br />
<hr /><hr />
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" id="block3">3s</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
        ul li ul{
            display: none;

            background-color: #000000;
            width: 400px;
            margin-top: 40px;
            float: left;
        }

    ul li ul li{
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        ul li:hover ul{
            display: block; /* display the dropdown */
        }

    ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul li ul hr{
            border-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: thin;
            border-style: solid;
        }

li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: -1px;


}



#block1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;

}

#block1:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
     padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-right: 29px;
    padding-left: 29px;
    color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#block2 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
     padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-right: 29px;
    padding-left: 29px;
    color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

}

#block2:hover {
   background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#block3 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-right: 29px;
    padding-left: 29px;
    color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#block3:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 39px;


}

hr {

    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Paste the code to the question, highlight it, and click on the "code formatting" icon in the tool bar (looks like `{}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i can recommend use position absolute so it doesnt affect other objects, and instead of margin use padding.

```
ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 40px;  
}
```

In case you want to have some free space between bar and drop down, then just add some div around that.

Comment: well, that worked pretty good, but now i have a big space between the dropdown li's and my nav.

Comment: What do you mean by a big space? Its fine if I put it these two lines and delete margin-top. Isn't it because padding-top is too large for you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `position` the 'ul' (dropdown-menu) within the 'li' (menu) `absolute` to the parent.

Every time you hover over your menu-item the menu gets displayed and the position of the menu-item changes. That's why it is flickering.

On top of that you should remove `margin-top` from your 'ul li ul' and make the listitems li `inline-block` instead of inline, so that the dropdown gets displayed undrneath the listitem.

i've created the codesnipped [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qENMQd)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has somthing to do with the placement of your tabs. What i am saying is: when your mouse hovers over the tab it shows the rest of the subtabs and therefore pushes the tab off the mouse therefore closing down the menu or in your case causing blinking.